# enqueue files to already running instance of vlc via command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, vlc-media-player

I am trying to do a python based workaround of the issue that there is no load next file in folder option in vlc. Is there a way to enqueue files to an already running instance of vlc media player from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `--playlist-enqueue` switch to add an item to the playlist instead of starting to play it right away:

```
vlc --playlist-enqueue c:\mp3s\foobar.mp3
```

Comment: VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.16-0-g5e70837d8d)
vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--playlist-enqueue'

Comment: doesn't work in ubuntu 22.04 in 2023.